# setInterval/setTimer not running after 5 mins of background time - Ionic

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, timer, ionic4

I have a requirement of a timer, that should send out notification (I am used onesignal API notification) after a particular user set value is reached.

For example if a user sets a value of 7 mins, the timer should send notification after 7 mins. The time a user can set varies from 1-59 mins. But even with using the background mode plugin (https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode), I cannot get the setInterval/setTimeout functions to work after 5 mins.

Tried using recursive setTimeout method:

```js
function startTimerCounter() {
  this.timerCounter = 0;
  const objThis = this; //store this.

  if (this.timerCounter >= this.setTime) {
    this.backgroundMode.disable();
    this.goalTimerReached = true;
  } else {
    this.backgroundMode.enable();
    this.timer = setTimeout(function request() {
      if (objThis.timerCounter === objThis.setTime) {
        //onesignal notification
        clearTimeout(objThis.timer);
      } else {
        ++objThis.timerCounter;
        objThis.timer = setTimeout(request, 1000);
      }
    }, 1000);
  }
}
```

Tried using the setInterval method:

```js
function startTimerCounter() {
  this.timerCounter = 0;
  const objThis = this; //store this.

  if (this.timerCounter >= this.setTime) {
    this.backgroundMode.disable();
    this.goalTimerReached = true;
  } else {
    this.backgroundMode.enable();
    this.timerCounter = 0;
    const objThis = this; //store this.
    this.timer = setInterval(() => {
      if (objThis.timerCounter === objThis.setTime) {
        //onesignal notification
        clearInterval(objThis.timer);
      } else {
        ++objThis.timerCounter;
      }
    }, 1000);
  }
}
```

The background activation notification at the top and I can see that the background mode is active. But the timer doesn't seem to be running after 5 mins.

any idea how this could be solved?

*** Update ****

Tried to invoke the function every 4 mins in the background to keep running which didn't work for me:

```
function startTimerCounter() {
      this.timerCounter = 0;
      const objThis = this; //store this.

      if (this.timerCounter >= this.setTime) {
        this.backgroundMode.disable();
        this.goalTimerReached = true;
      } else {
        this.backgroundMode.enable();
        this.timerCounter = 0;
        const objThis = this; //store this.
        this.timer = setInterval(() => {
          if (objThis.timerCounter === objThis.setTime) {
            //onesignal notification
            clearInterval(objThis.timer);
          } else {
            ++objThis.timerCounter;
          }
        }, 1000);

     this.backgroundMode.on('activate').subscribe(() => {
        setInterval(function () {
          this.startTimerCounter();
        }, 240000);
      })
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

use this plugin : `cordova-plugin-background`

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', function () {

            cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.enable();

             cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.onactivate = function () {

               setInterval(function () {

                  YourFunctionHere();

                }, 300000);
             }
           }, false);
```

your app it' well refrech in backround every 5 Min

> 300000 millisecond = 5 min

Comment: Tried this but still doesn't work. The setInterval function wouldn't work in the background properly.

Comment: So this is what I found online:
This is expected behaviour - when the application pauses, so do all setInterval's running and (and setTimeouts pending). 

Also I have updated the question with how I have tried using the method you have mentioned. Could you check and let me know where it would be going wrong.